# Why do sub-editors in GWT's editor framework need to be package-private?

Tags: java, gwt

I've just tried out [GWT's editor framework](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html#Provided_Adapters) and got it working for a small example. But I was wondering why sub-editors need to be package-private?

There is a comment in an example in the linked page that specifically mentions package-protected fields, but I cannot find the reason why.

```
// Sub-editors are retrieved from package-protected fields, usually initialized with UiBinder.
// Many Editors have no interesting logic in them
public class PersonEditor extends Dialog implements Editor<Person> {
    Label nameEditor;
    AddressEditor addressEditor;
    ...
}
```

In the example I tried myself, I only got it working if my sub-editors are package-private, if i make them private, the binding does no longer work.

Can anyone explain to me why this restriction exists? It makes my coding style appear a bit inconsistently. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar to UiBinder, the generator for an `EditorDriver` generates classes along-side `Editor` classes. These classes need access to the editors to be able to work with them.

Put differently, the editor framework won't modify you classes (*there's no magic*), so you have to somehow expose your sub-editors: package-private is enough, but `public` would of course work too.
The best way to understand what's going on is to pass the `-gen` option (followed by a directory path) to the GWT compiler of dev mode, so that it outputs all the generated classes to disk. Be warned though: the editor framework is really hard to comprehend!

Also, if your editor extends some other class in another package that contains a sub-editor (that you want to inherit), that subeditor must be visible from the package of the child class, so it has to be `public` in the parent class, or be explicitly exposed by the child class (using an accessor method that's not `private`).

Answer (score 2):

GWT generates an editor delegate (and a context) for each editor that will be used by the driver. This delegate (and context) require access to the subeditors they will manipulate as part of passing data in and out of the editors. As these are written in Java, and not using JSNI to access private fields, your editors must be accessible to other classes in the same package.

That said, there are several options for you. The first is to make them explicitly `public`, or `protected`, which may or may not fit your code style. The second is to expose them via methods, with the method named the same as the property to be edited, optionally suffixed with 'Editor'. See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html#Editor_contract for more details on this.

This restriction is the same as the uibinder restriction - the field must be accessible to read/write it from generated classes. If you just have a `private Label nameEditor;`, then your IDE will likely complain at you that this is unused, as it can't see the code which hasnt been generated which could access this fields. Making it more public than `private` makes it clear that it will be used outside that single class.

Comment: Thanks Colin, I wish I could accept more than one answer. Stack Overflow is truly great, before asking the question I just saw a video of your talk on Data Binding and editors at Senchacon 2011 in which you also briefly refer to Thomas Broyer regarding MVP.

Comment: His answer is great - I started mine and thought about not posting it, but I thought it added a few pieces to the discussion that could be worthwhile to the next reader. Hope the video was helpful!